# Unable to ExecuteScalar() because of authentication error

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I am following a Microsoft tutorial for setting up forms-based authentication, and getting a failure.

Here is the tutorial:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/301240/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio

This line is failing:

```
// Execute command and fetch pwd field into lookupPassword string.
lookupPassword = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I am getting this error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'HOME\TSLAB1$'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)

TSLAB1 is the name of the server. I expected to see the SQL user here instead, NOT the windows user.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` try with this maybe that help out your problem.

Comment: That's exactly how IIS works, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Thanks Lex, how would you recommend executing a command using a SQL username and password?